# AWS Lambda Mongodb Error: topology was destroyed

Tags: node.js, mongodb, lambda

I've created a Lambda function for storing data to Mongodb by this function in Node JS:

```
const Connection = MongoClient.connect(...);
const demoColl = Connection.collection('demo');
demoColl.bulkWrite(bulkArray...);
client.close();
```

I've tested by `invoke local` smoothly, also success when run one by one.

But my application calling the function  3-5 times per second, lambda showing this error message

> "errorMessage":"topology was destroyed","errorType":"MongoError"

I've done a research it cause closing the db when the function still running. How can I prevent one of the connection close will not affect another Lambda function?

Comment: This happens when the connection is closed but you still try to access models.

Comment: Lambda - you mean AWS Lambda?

Comment: Yes is AWS Lambda, sorry for missing this info

Answer (score 2):

```
import * as mongoose from "mongoose";

(<any>mongoose).Promise = global.Promise;
let cacheDb: mongoose.Connection = null;
export let connect = () => {
    if (cacheDb && mongoose.connection.readyState === 1) {
        return cacheDb;
    } else {
        // Mongoose config and setting global Promise
        mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGODB_URI, {
            promiseLibrary: global.Promise,
            connectTimeoutMS: 20 * 1000
        }).then(() => {
            cacheDb = mongoose.connection;
            return cacheDb;
        }).catch((err) => {
            console.log(err);
        });
    }
};
export let disconnect = () => {
    mongoose.disconnect();
}
```

I have this file that caches the MongoDB Connection and reuses if available. Just make sure that this is outside the lambda handler.

And, it's not a good idea to close connection as this will make your lambda to connect every time the lambda is invoked - additional burden on DB and Lambda execution time.

Reference: https://blog.cloudboost.io/i-wish-i-knew-how-to-use-mongodb-connection-in-aws-lambda-f91cd2694ae5

Comment: This is TypeScript, FYI